# IBM Bluemix - NodeJS: unable to resolve the dependency in the manifest

Tags: node.js, npm, ibm-cloud, manifest

I am using IBM Blue mix dev ops build and deploy. My application is nodejs application, which I created using nodejs express framework and added all the required files like manifest.yml.

Previous Issues which i fixed:
1. I have to add .ymml file myself
2. the project name was already occupied, i supplied new one.
3. Because I had nested directories and it's in 2nd sub directory, so build step was also failing, I add /path/path/ then it was success.

Issue:
4. On deploy, I am getting this error.

```
   -----> Downloaded app package (28K)
-----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (13M)
Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/nodejs-buildpack'...
Submodule 'compile-extensions' (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/compile-extensions.git) registered for path 'compile-extensions'
Cloning into 'compile-extensions'...
-------> Buildpack version 1.5.15
-----> Creating runtime environment
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  4.2.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       Downloading and installing node 4.2.x...
DEPENDENCY MISSING IN MANIFEST:
Unfortunately, we are either unable to resolve the dependency into
a binary and version number or the requested version or version range is not supported.
Please replace the URL with a valid link or the requested version/range
with a supported version or version range.
-----> Build failed
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       https://help.heroku.com/
       Love,
       Heroku
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed

FAILED
BuildpackCompileFailed

TIP: use 'cf logs myapplication --recent' for more information

Finished: FAILED

Stage has no runtime information
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error in `project.json` file.

It had:

```
 },
  "repository": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.2.x"
  }
```

On my local machine, I was running `4.4.x`. So I changed it, and now the application is working.