# Bluemix Deployment Issue Node.js w/ Express

Tags: node.js, express, ibm-cloud

I'm having issues with my deployment failing, and have no idea why. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have spent a stupid amount of hours trying find out what's going on with no luck. I'm pretty sure it might be something dumb that I'm missing. It's odd. The build will succeed, and it will server. Then it crashes, and I have zero ideas why at the moment.

Using the Node.js Buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack

**Package.json file**

```
{
    "name": "core-backend-server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.1.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.13.2",
        "cors": "^2.8.1",
        "express": "^4.13.0",
        "express-error-middleware": "^1.3.0",
        "express-jwt": "^3.0.1",
        "jade": "^1.11.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^5.0.2",
        "lodash": "^3.10.0",
        "mongodb": "^2.1.16",
        "mongoskin": "^2.1.0",
        "q": "^1.4.1",
        "request": "^2.58.0",
        "rootpath": "^0.1.2",
        "cfenv": "1.0.x"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node" : "7.8.x"
    }
}
```

**Bluemix Deployment Logs:**

```
4/16/2017 1:40:29 PM    OUT APP Exit status 143
4/16/2017 1:40:29 PM    OUT CELL    Exit status 0
4/16/2017 1:40:33 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-     4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
4/16/2017 1:40:33 PM    OUT STG Creating container
4/16/2017 1:40:48 PM    OUT STG Successfully created container
4/16/2017 1:40:48 PM    OUT STG Downloading app package...
4/16/2017 1:40:55 PM    OUT CELL    Successfully destroyed container
4/16/2017 1:40:56 PM    OUT STG Downloaded app package (44.6M)
4/16/2017 1:40:56 PM    OUT STG Downloading build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 1:40:57 PM    OUT STG Downloaded build artifacts cache (4.1M)
4/16/2017 1:40:57 PM    OUT STG Staging...
4/16/2017 1:41:00 PM    OUT STG -------> Buildpack version 1.5.32
4/16/2017 1:41:00 PM    OUT STG -----> Creating runtime environment
4/16/2017 1:41:00 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 1:41:00 PM    OUT STG NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
4/16/2017 1:41:00 PM    OUT STG NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
4/16/2017 1:41:00 PM    OUT STG NODE_VERBOSE=false
4/16/2017 1:41:00 PM    OUT STG NODE_ENV=production
4/16/2017 1:41:00 PM    OUT STG NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
4/16/2017 1:41:00 PM    OUT STG -----> Installing binaries
4/16/2017 1:41:00 PM    OUT STG engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
4/16/2017 1:41:00 PM    OUT STG engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
4/16/2017 1:41:00 PM    OUT STG Downloading and installing node 4.8.2...
4/16/2017 1:41:03 PM    OUT STG -----> Restoring cache
4/16/2017 1:41:03 PM    OUT STG Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
4/16/2017 1:41:03 PM    OUT STG -----> Building dependencies
4/16/2017 1:41:03 PM    OUT STG Rebuilding any native modules
4/16/2017 1:41:06 PM    OUT STG body-parser@1.17.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/body-parser
-- I ADDED: DELETED SECTION OF MODULES INSTALLING --
4/16/2017 1:41:06 PM    OUT STG jodid25519@1.0.2 /tmp/app/node_modules/jodid25519
4/16/2017 1:41:06 PM    OUT STG uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 /tmp/app/node_modules/uglify-to-browserify
4/16/2017 1:41:06 PM    OUT STG Installing any new modules (package.json)
4/16/2017 1:41:09 PM    OUT STG -----> Caching build
4/16/2017 1:41:09 PM    OUT STG Clearing previous node cache
4/16/2017 1:41:09 PM    OUT STG Saving 3 cacheDirectories (default):
4/16/2017 1:41:09 PM    OUT STG - .npm (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 1:41:09 PM    OUT STG - .cache/yarn (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 1:41:09 PM    OUT STG - bower_components (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 1:41:09 PM    OUT STG -----> Build succeeded!
4/16/2017 1:41:23 PM    OUT STG Exit status 0
4/16/2017 1:41:23 PM    OUT STG Staging complete
4/16/2017 1:41:23 PM    OUT STG Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 1:41:23 PM    OUT STG Uploading build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 1:41:23 PM    OUT STG Uploading droplet...
4/16/2017 1:41:30 PM    OUT STG Uploaded droplet (43.7M)
4/16/2017 1:41:30 PM    OUT STG Destroying container
4/16/2017 1:41:31 PM    OUT CELL    Creating container
4/16/2017 1:41:33 PM    OUT CELL    Successfully created container
4/16/2017 1:41:38 PM    OUT CELL    Starting health monitoring of container
4/16/2017 1:41:39 PM    OUT APP Server listening on port ---- 8080
4/16/2017 1:41:40 PM    OUT CELL    Container became healthy
4/16/2017 1:43:28 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"name"=>"Speakey Pipeline", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "buildpack"=>"https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack"})
4/16/2017 1:44:54 PM    OUT CELL    Exit status 0
4/16/2017 1:44:54 PM    OUT APP Exit status 143
4/16/2017 1:44:54 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
4/16/2017 1:44:54 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
4/16/2017 1:44:56 PM    OUT CELL    Successfully destroyed container
4/16/2017 1:45:16 PM    OUT STG Downloading app package...
4/16/2017 1:45:25 PM    OUT STG Downloaded app package (44.6M)
4/16/2017 1:45:25 PM    OUT STG Staging...
4/16/2017 1:45:28 PM    OUT STG -----> Creating runtime environment
4/16/2017 1:45:28 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 1:45:28 PM    OUT STG NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
4/16/2017 1:45:28 PM    OUT STG NODE_VERBOSE=false
4/16/2017 1:45:28 PM    OUT STG NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
4/16/2017 1:45:28 PM    OUT STG -----> Installing binaries
4/16/2017 1:45:28 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG Downloading and installing node ...
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG DEPENDENCY MISSING IN MANIFEST:
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG Unfortunately, we are either unable to resolve the dependency into
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG a binary and version number or the requested version or version range is not supported.
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG Please replace the URL with a valid link or the requested version/range
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG with a supported version or version range.
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG -----> Build failed
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG Failed to compile droplet
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG We're sorry this build is failing! You find more info about the nodejs buildpack here:
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/index.html
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG - node_modules checked into source control
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG Exit status 223
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG Staging failed: Exited with status 223
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG Destroying container
4/16/2017 1:45:48 PM    OUT STG Successfully destroyed container
4/16/2017 2:04:52 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"name"=>"Speakey Pipeline", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})
4/16/2017 2:06:06 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
4/16/2017 2:06:07 PM    OUT STG Creating container
4/16/2017 2:06:20 PM    OUT STG Successfully created container
4/16/2017 2:06:20 PM    OUT STG Downloading app package...
4/16/2017 2:06:31 PM    OUT STG Downloaded app package (44.6M)
4/16/2017 2:06:31 PM    OUT STG Downloading build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 2:06:31 PM    OUT STG Downloaded build artifacts cache (258B)
4/16/2017 2:06:31 PM    OUT STG Staging...
4/16/2017 2:06:34 PM    OUT STG -------> Buildpack version 1.5.32
4/16/2017 2:06:34 PM    OUT STG -----> Creating runtime environment
4/16/2017 2:06:34 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 2:06:34 PM    OUT STG NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
4/16/2017 2:06:34 PM    OUT STG NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
4/16/2017 2:06:34 PM    OUT STG NODE_VERBOSE=false
4/16/2017 2:06:34 PM    OUT STG NODE_ENV=production
4/16/2017 2:06:34 PM    OUT STG -----> Installing binaries
4/16/2017 2:06:34 PM    OUT STG engines.node (package.json):  ^6.9.x
4/16/2017 2:06:34 PM    OUT STG engines.npm (package.json):   ^2.1.x
4/16/2017 2:06:34 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 2:06:34 PM    OUT STG Downloading and installing node 6.10.2...
4/16/2017 2:06:36 PM    OUT STG Downloaded [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/node/node-6.10.2-linux-x64-9f48b587.tgz]
4/16/2017 2:06:57 PM    OUT STG -----> Restoring cache
4/16/2017 2:06:58 PM    OUT STG Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
4/16/2017 2:06:58 PM    OUT STG -----> Building dependencies
4/16/2017 2:06:58 PM    OUT STG Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
4/16/2017 2:06:58 PM    OUT STG Rebuilding any native modules
4/16/2017 2:07:00 PM    OUT STG body-parser@1.17.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/body-parser
-- I ADDED: DELETED SECTION OF MODULES INSTALLING --
4/16/2017 2:07:00 PM    OUT STG jsbn@0.1.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/jsbn
4/16/2017 2:07:00 PM    OUT STG Installing any new modules (package.json)
4/16/2017 2:07:04 PM    OUT STG -----> Caching build
4/16/2017 2:07:04 PM    OUT STG Clearing previous node cache
4/16/2017 2:07:04 PM    OUT STG - .npm (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 2:07:04 PM    OUT STG - .cache/yarn (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 2:07:04 PM    OUT STG - bower_components (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 2:07:04 PM    OUT STG -----> Build succeeded!
4/16/2017 2:07:27 PM    OUT STG Exit status 0
4/16/2017 2:07:27 PM    OUT STG Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 2:07:27 PM    OUT STG Uploading build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 2:07:27 PM    OUT STG Uploading droplet...
4/16/2017 2:07:27 PM    OUT STG Uploaded build artifacts cache (258B)
4/16/2017 2:07:30 PM    OUT STG Uploading complete
4/16/2017 2:07:31 PM    OUT STG Destroying container
4/16/2017 2:07:31 PM    OUT CELL    Creating container
4/16/2017 2:07:42 PM    OUT STG Successfully destroyed container
4/16/2017 2:07:43 PM    OUT CELL    Successfully created container
4/16/2017 2:07:50 PM    OUT CELL    Starting health monitoring of container
4/16/2017 2:07:51 PM    OUT APP Server listening on port ---- 8080
4/16/2017 2:07:52 PM    OUT CELL    Container became healthy
4/16/2017 2:11:00 PM    OUT APP Exit status 143
4/16/2017 2:11:00 PM    OUT CELL    Exit status 0
4/16/2017 2:11:00 PM    OUT CELL    Destroying container
4/16/2017 2:11:00 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
4/16/2017 2:11:01 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
4/16/2017 2:11:02 PM    OUT STG Creating container
4/16/2017 2:11:08 PM    OUT CELL    Successfully destroyed container
4/16/2017 2:11:25 PM    OUT STG Downloading app package...
4/16/2017 2:11:33 PM    OUT STG Downloaded app package (44.6M)
4/16/2017 2:11:33 PM    OUT STG Downloading build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 2:11:34 PM    OUT STG Downloaded build artifacts cache (258B)
4/16/2017 2:11:34 PM    OUT STG Staging...
4/16/2017 2:11:36 PM    OUT STG -------> Buildpack version 1.5.32
4/16/2017 2:11:36 PM    OUT STG -----> Creating runtime environment
4/16/2017 2:11:36 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 2:11:36 PM    OUT STG NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
4/16/2017 2:11:36 PM    OUT STG NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
4/16/2017 2:11:36 PM    OUT STG NODE_ENV=production
4/16/2017 2:11:36 PM    OUT STG -----> Installing binaries
4/16/2017 2:11:36 PM    OUT STG engines.npm (package.json):   ^2.1.x
4/16/2017 2:11:36 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 2:11:36 PM    OUT STG Downloading and installing node 7.8.0...
4/16/2017 2:11:39 PM    OUT STG Downloading and installing npm ^2.1.x (replacing version 4.2.0)...
4/16/2017 2:11:54 PM    OUT STG -----> Restoring cache
4/16/2017 2:11:54 PM    OUT STG Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
4/16/2017 2:11:54 PM    OUT STG -----> Building dependencies
4/16/2017 2:11:54 PM    OUT STG Rebuilding any native modules
4/16/2017 2:11:57 PM    OUT STG bcryptjs@2.4.3 /tmp/app/node_modules/bcryptjs
-- I ADDED: DELETED SECTION OF MODULES INSTALLING --
4/16/2017 2:11:57 PM    OUT STG jodid25519@1.0.2 /tmp/app/node_modules/jodid25519
4/16/2017 2:11:57 PM    OUT STG uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 /tmp/app/node_modules/uglify-to-browserify
4/16/2017 2:11:57 PM    OUT STG Installing any new modules (package.json)
4/16/2017 2:12:00 PM    OUT STG -----> Caching build
4/16/2017 2:12:00 PM    OUT STG Clearing previous node cache
4/16/2017 2:12:00 PM    OUT STG Saving 3 cacheDirectories (default):
4/16/2017 2:12:00 PM    OUT STG - .npm (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 2:12:00 PM    OUT STG - .cache/yarn (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 2:12:00 PM    OUT STG - bower_components (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 2:12:01 PM    OUT STG -----> Build succeeded!
4/16/2017 2:12:28 PM    OUT STG Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 2:12:28 PM    OUT STG Uploading build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 2:12:28 PM    OUT STG Uploaded build artifacts cache (260B)
4/16/2017 2:12:33 PM    OUT STG Uploaded droplet (49.3M)
4/16/2017 2:12:33 PM    OUT STG Uploading complete
4/16/2017 2:12:33 PM    OUT STG Destroying container
4/16/2017 2:12:34 PM    OUT CELL    Creating container
4/16/2017 2:12:48 PM    OUT STG Successfully destroyed container
4/16/2017 2:12:50 PM    OUT CELL    Successfully created container
4/16/2017 2:12:58 PM    OUT CELL    Starting health monitoring of container
4/16/2017 2:12:59 PM    OUT APP Server listening on port ---- 8080
4/16/2017 2:25:44 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"name"=>"Speakey Pipeline", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})
4/16/2017 2:27:00 PM    OUT CELL    Exit status 0
4/16/2017 2:27:00 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
4/16/2017 2:27:00 PM    OUT APP Exit status 143
4/16/2017 2:27:00 PM    OUT CELL    Destroying container
4/16/2017 2:27:01 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
4/16/2017 2:27:02 PM    OUT STG Creating container
4/16/2017 2:27:12 PM    OUT CELL    Successfully destroyed container
4/16/2017 2:27:18 PM    OUT STG Successfully created container
4/16/2017 2:27:18 PM    OUT STG Downloading app package...
4/16/2017 2:27:28 PM    OUT STG Downloaded app package (44.3M)
4/16/2017 2:27:28 PM    OUT STG Downloading build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 2:27:28 PM    OUT STG Downloaded build artifacts cache (260B)
4/16/2017 2:27:28 PM    OUT STG Staging...
4/16/2017 2:27:31 PM    OUT STG -------> Buildpack version 1.5.32
4/16/2017 2:27:31 PM    OUT STG -----> Creating runtime environment
4/16/2017 2:27:31 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 2:27:31 PM    OUT STG NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
4/16/2017 2:27:31 PM    OUT STG NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
4/16/2017 2:27:31 PM    OUT STG NODE_VERBOSE=false
4/16/2017 2:27:31 PM    OUT STG NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
4/16/2017 2:27:31 PM    OUT STG -----> Installing binaries
4/16/2017 2:27:31 PM    OUT STG engines.node (package.json):  >=4.4.x
4/16/2017 2:27:31 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 2:27:54 PM    OUT STG Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
4/16/2017 2:27:54 PM    OUT STG -----> Building dependencies
4/16/2017 2:27:54 PM    OUT STG Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
4/16/2017 2:27:54 PM    OUT STG Rebuilding any native modules
4/16/2017 2:27:57 PM    OUT STG bcryptjs@2.4.3 /tmp/app/node_modules/bcryptjs
-- I ADDED: DELETED SECTION OF MODULES INSTALLING --
4/16/2017 2:27:57 PM    OUT STG jodid25519@1.0.2 /tmp/app/node_modules/jodid25519
4/16/2017 2:27:57 PM    OUT STG Installing any new modules (package.json)
4/16/2017 2:27:59 PM    OUT STG -----> Caching build
4/16/2017 2:27:59 PM    OUT STG Clearing previous node cache
4/16/2017 2:27:59 PM    OUT STG Saving 3 cacheDirectories (default):
4/16/2017 2:27:59 PM    OUT STG - .npm (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 2:27:59 PM    OUT STG - .cache/yarn (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 2:27:59 PM    OUT STG - bower_components (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 2:27:59 PM    OUT STG -----> Build succeeded!
4/16/2017 2:28:24 PM    OUT STG Exit status 0
4/16/2017 2:28:24 PM    OUT STG Staging complete
4/16/2017 2:28:24 PM    OUT STG Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 2:28:24 PM    OUT STG Uploading build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 2:28:24 PM    OUT STG Uploading droplet...
4/16/2017 2:28:24 PM    OUT STG Uploaded build artifacts cache (258B)
4/16/2017 2:28:29 PM    OUT STG Uploading complete
4/16/2017 2:28:29 PM    OUT STG Destroying container
4/16/2017 2:28:42 PM    OUT STG Successfully destroyed container
4/16/2017 2:28:55 PM    OUT APP Server listening on port ---- 8080
4/16/2017 2:44:03 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"name"=>"Speakey Pipeline", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "buildpack"=>"https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack"})
4/16/2017 2:45:18 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
4/16/2017 2:45:18 PM    OUT APP Exit status 143
4/16/2017 2:45:18 PM    OUT CELL    Exit status 0
4/16/2017 2:45:18 PM    OUT CELL    Destroying container
4/16/2017 2:45:19 PM    OUT API Updated app with guid e6824266-a05f-4f99-9ca4-69e303dfacfd ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
4/16/2017 2:45:29 PM    OUT CELL    Successfully destroyed container
4/16/2017 2:45:39 PM    OUT STG Successfully created container
4/16/2017 2:45:39 PM    OUT STG Downloading app package...
4/16/2017 2:45:47 PM    OUT STG Downloading build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 2:45:47 PM    OUT STG Downloaded build artifacts cache (258B)
4/16/2017 2:45:47 PM    OUT STG Staging...
4/16/2017 2:45:52 PM    OUT STG -------> Buildpack version 1.5.32
4/16/2017 2:45:52 PM    OUT STG -----> Creating runtime environment
4/16/2017 2:45:52 PM    OUT STG NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
4/16/2017 2:45:52 PM    OUT STG NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
4/16/2017 2:45:52 PM    OUT STG NODE_VERBOSE=false
4/16/2017 2:45:52 PM    OUT STG NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
4/16/2017 2:45:52 PM    OUT STG -----> Installing binaries
4/16/2017 2:45:52 PM    OUT STG engines.node (package.json):  >=4.4.x
4/16/2017 2:45:52 PM    OUT STG engines.npm (package.json):   >=2.1.x
4/16/2017 2:45:52 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 2:45:52 PM    OUT STG Downloading and installing node 7.8.0...
4/16/2017 2:45:54 PM    OUT STG Downloaded [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/node/node-7.8.0-linux-x64-a72100f9.tgz]
4/16/2017 2:45:55 PM    OUT STG Downloading and installing npm >=2.1.x (replacing version 4.2.0)...
4/16/2017 2:46:15 PM    OUT STG -----> Restoring cache
4/16/2017 2:46:16 PM    OUT STG Loading 3 from cacheDirectories (default):
4/16/2017 2:46:16 PM    OUT STG - .npm (not cached - skipping)
4/16/2017 2:46:16 PM    OUT STG - .cache/yarn (not cached - skipping)
4/16/2017 2:46:16 PM    OUT STG - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
4/16/2017 2:46:16 PM    OUT STG -----> Building dependencies
4/16/2017 2:46:16 PM    OUT STG Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
4/16/2017 2:46:16 PM    OUT STG Rebuilding any native modules
4/16/2017 2:46:19 PM    OUT STG bcryptjs@2.4.3 /tmp/app/node_modules/bcryptjs
-- I ADDED: DELETED SECTION OF MODULES INSTALLING --
4/16/2017 2:46:19 PM    OUT STG uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 /tmp/app/node_modules/uglify-to-browserify
4/16/2017 2:46:19 PM    OUT STG Installing any new modules (package.json)
4/16/2017 2:46:21 PM    OUT STG -----> Caching build
4/16/2017 2:46:21 PM    OUT STG Clearing previous node cache
4/16/2017 2:46:21 PM    OUT STG Saving 3 cacheDirectories (default):
4/16/2017 2:46:21 PM    OUT STG - .npm (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 2:46:21 PM    OUT STG - .cache/yarn (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 2:46:21 PM    OUT STG - bower_components (nothing to cache)
4/16/2017 2:46:21 PM    OUT STG -----> Build succeeded!
4/16/2017 2:46:43 PM    OUT STG Exit status 0
4/16/2017 2:46:43 PM    OUT STG Staging complete
4/16/2017 2:46:43 PM    OUT STG Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 2:46:43 PM    OUT STG Uploading build artifacts cache...
4/16/2017 2:46:43 PM    OUT STG Uploading droplet...
4/16/2017 2:46:44 PM    OUT STG Uploaded build artifacts cache (256B)
4/16/2017 2:46:51 PM    OUT STG Uploaded droplet (50.2M)
4/16/2017 2:46:51 PM    OUT STG Uploading complete
4/16/2017 2:46:51 PM    OUT STG Destroying container
4/16/2017 2:47:10 PM    OUT CELL    Successfully created container
4/16/2017 2:47:17 PM    OUT CELL    Starting health monitoring of container
4/16/2017 2:47:18 PM    OUT APP Server listening on port ---- 8080
4/16/2017 2:47:20 PM    OUT CELL    Container became healthy
```

**THE ERROR:**
It like it's not using the package specified version, and then it tries a bunch of different builds repeatedly.

```
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG DEPENDENCY MISSING IN MANIFEST:
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG Unfortunately, we are either unable to resolve the dependency into
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG a binary and version number or the requested version or version range is not supported.
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG Please replace the URL with a valid link or the requested version/range
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG with a supported version or version range.
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG -----> Build failed
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG Failed to compile droplet
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG We're sorry this build is failing! You find more info about the nodejs buildpack here:
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/index.html
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG - node_modules checked into source control
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG 
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    OUT STG Exit status 223
4/16/2017 1:45:29 PM    ERR STG Staging failed: Exited with status 223
```

**APP LOGS**

```
Done uploading
OK

Stopping app Speakey Pipeline in org SpeechDictation / space dev 
OK

Starting app Speakey Pipeline in org SpeechDictation / space dev 
Creating container
Successfully created container
Downloading app package...
Downloaded app package (44.3M)
Downloading build artifacts cache...
Downloaded build artifacts cache (262B)
Staging...
-------> Buildpack version 1.5.32

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  7.8.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Downloading and installing node 7.8.0...
       Downloaded [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/node/node-7.8.0-linux-x64-a72100f9.tgz]
-----> Restoring cache
       Skipping cache restore (disabled by config)
-----> Building dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       bcryptjs@2.4.3 /tmp/app/node_modules/bcryptjs
--- SECTION OF DEPENDENCIES I REMOVED FOR SPACE
       safe-buffer@5.0.1 /tmp/app/node_modules/safe-buffer
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Skipping cache save (disabled by config)
-----> Build succeeded!
Staging complete
Uploading droplet, build artifacts cache...
Uploading build artifacts cache...
Uploading droplet...
Uploaded build artifacts cache (256B)
Uploaded droplet (49.1M)
Uploading complete
Destroying container

0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
1 of 1 instances running

App started


OK

App Speakey Pipeline was started using this command `node app.js`

Showing health and status for app Speakey Pipeline in org SpeechDictation / space dev as 
OK

requested state: started
instances: 1/1
usage: 64M x 1 instances
urls: spekra.mybluemix.net
last uploaded: Sun Apr 16 15:53:50 UTC 2017
stack: cflinuxfs2
buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack

     state     since                    cpu    memory         disk           details
#0   running   2017-04-16 03:55:33 PM   0.0%   30.6M of 64M   284.1M of 1G
Sending deployment success of Speakey Pipeline to IBM DevOps Services...
IBM DevOps Services notified successfully.
FAILED
```

Comment: My version might have been to high; so I'm trying this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38047718/ibm-bluemix-nodejs-unable-to-resolve-the-dependency-in-the-manifest

Comment: Can you highlight the error? (might want to check application logs?)

Comment: @majidarif just updated the ticket. It's weird. It's like it's trying different scenarios, and it will get it up and running, and then crash it.

Comment: I have tried changing the package.json node version to all of the supported versions, and are getting the same error.

Comment: @majidarif just added the app logs

Comment: i wonder if you HAVE to have a manifest file now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there nodejs buildpacks for the latest version supports only 4.2.x; so it was a versioning issue....

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when I deployed a tutorial early this year on using Bluemix and Watson services. The fix that I put in place was to remove the engine specification from my package.json file. That way I ensured that Bluemix installed it's default engine when it deployed my app.